# Calculating L1 Cache Bandwidth of GPU

Tags: caching, architecture, gpu, bandwidth

I am trying to find out how to calculate the L1 cache bandwidth of the Nvidia Tesla V100 GPU, and I stumbled upon this article which finds the L1 bandwidth of the GTX 470 by using the 128-byte cache line size and the clock (.607 GHz) to get .607x128 = 77.696 GB/s per SM.

https://www.beyond3d.com/content/reviews/55/7 (11th paragraph)

Is this the correct way of finding the cache bandwidth? Why does it only depend on the cache line size and not on the memory bus width or the width of whatever bus the data is being put on? I am new to GPUs (though I'm guessing this has more to do with understanding how a cache works) and am trying to understand why their calculation makes sense.